# Selectedindexchanged for DDL is not firing (AutoPostBack = "true")

Tags: c#, asp.net, drop-down-menu

so here's what's going on. I have a table that is created in code-behind like so:

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
            RetrievedValue = SearchBox.Text;
            GetData(RetrievedValue); //Creates a Datatable, populates it and binds it to a GridView
    }
```

Now, I understand that using if(!IsPostBack) is a valid solution to this problem. Unfortunately if I try this the table is not created. I believe this is because I am using the result of my searchbox to create the table, but I am uncertain. (To be honest, I think this is where the problem lies, but I'll tell you the rest anyway)

So I want to add a row to this table using the footer of the gridview to show three Dropdownlists, where the selection of one list item updates the next list. So far I have been able to get the first Dropdownlist working fine, however when I select an option nothing happens. Here is my Dropdownlist code:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" AppendDataBoundItems='True' 
       DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" AutoPostBack = "true" EnableViewState = "true"
       OnSelectedIndexChanged="DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged"
       DataTextField="field1" DataValueField="field1">
               <asp:ListItem Value="-2" Text="--choose--" Selected="True" />
               <asp:ListItem Value="-1" Text="ALL" />
</asp:DropDownList>

<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server"> 
       <Triggers> 
               <asp:AsyncPostbackTrigger ControlID="DropDownList1" EventName="SelectedIndexChanged" /> 
       </Triggers> 
</asp:UpdatePanel> 


<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConflictDetection="CompareAllValues" 
    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:MyConnectionString %>" 
    OldValuesParameterFormatString="original_{0}" 
    SelectCommand="SELECT DISTINCT field1 FROM table">
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Here is my c# method:

```
protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("SelectedIndexChanged"); //not being called
    }
```

Any help for this problem would be greatly appreciated! I know it's something to do with the Page_Load, but I am not sure how to do it any other way!

Thanks heaps :)

Here is the GridView code:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView8" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" AutoGenerateColumns="false" 
     AllowSorting="True" CellPadding="4" OnRowDataBound="GridView8_RowDataBound" 
     ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None" PageSize="20" Width="100%" ShowFooter="false" >
     <Columns>
       <asp:TemplateField HeaderText=" ">
         <FooterTemplate>
            <asp:LinkButton id="Insert" runat="server" CausesValidation="True" Text="Insert"  OnClick="Insert_Click" /><br />
            <asp:LinkButton id="Cancel" runat="server" CausesValidation="True" Text="Cancel" OnClick="Cancel_Click"  />
         </FooterTemplate>
       </asp:TemplateField>

       <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="FieldName">
         <ItemTemplate>
            <%# Eval("FieldName")%>
         </ItemTemplate>
         <FooterTemplate>
            <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" AppendDataBoundItems='True' DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" AutoPostBack = "true"
                  EnableViewState = "true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged"
                  DataTextField="field1" DataValueField="field1">
                  <asp:ListItem Value="-2" Text="--choose--" Selected="True" />
                  <asp:ListItem Value="-1" Text="ALL" />
            </asp:DropDownList>

            <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server"> 
                  <Triggers> 
                      <asp:AsyncPostbackTrigger ControlID="DropDownList1" EventName="SelectedIndexChanged" /> 
                  </Triggers> 
            </asp:UpdatePanel> 

            <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
                 ConflictDetection="CompareAllValues" 
                 ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:MyConnectionString %>" 
                 OldValuesParameterFormatString="original_{0}" 
                 SelectCommand="SELECT DISTINCT field1 FROM table">
            </asp:SqlDataSource>
         </FooterTemplate>
       </asp:TemplateField>

                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="FieldName2">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <%# Eval("FieldName2")%>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                        <FooterTemplate>
                            <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList2" runat="server" AppendDataBoundItems='True' Enabled="false">
                                              <asp:ListItem Value="-2" Text="--choose--" />
                                              <asp:ListItem Value="-1" Text="ALL" />
                            </asp:DropDownList>
                        </FooterTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>

                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="FieldName3">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <%# Eval("FieldName3") %>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                        <FooterTemplate>
                            <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList3" runat="server" AppendDataBoundItems='True' Enabled="false">
                                              <asp:ListItem Value="-2" Text="--choose--" />
                                              <asp:ListItem Value="-1" Text="ALL" />
                            </asp:DropDownList>
                        </FooterTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                </Columns>  
            </asp:GridView>
```

And the getData method:

```
protected void GetData(String str)
{
    DataTable table = new DataTable();
    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyConnectionString"].ConnectionString))
    {
        string sql = "SELECT FieldName3, FieldName2, FieldName1 FROM table t WHERE field5 LIKE @field5";
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn))
        {
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@field5", str));

            using (SqlDataAdapter ad = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
            {
                ad.Fill(table);
            }
        }
    }

    /*Populate table with adjusted data*/
    DataTable table2 = new DataTable();
    if (str.Length != 0 && table.Rows.Count != 0)
    {
        String NameCodes1 = table.Rows[0]["FieldName3"].ToString();
        String NameCodes2 = table.Rows[0]["FieldName2"].ToString();
        String NameCodes3 = table.Rows[0]["FieldName1"].ToString();

        if (String.CompareOrdinal(NameCodes1, "%") == 0) //if ALL
        {
            DataColumn dcol = new DataColumn("FieldName3", typeof(System.String));
            table2.Columns.Add(dcol);
            DataColumn dcol2 = new DataColumn("FieldName2", typeof(System.String));
            table2.Columns.Add(dcol2);
            DataColumn dcol3 = new DataColumn("FieldName1", typeof(System.String));
            table2.Columns.Add(dcol3);
            CheckPHO(NameCodes2, NameCodes3, table2, 0); //adds rows depending on whether there are multiple codes in the field
        }
        else //not ALL
        {
            pracCodes = Regex.Replace(NameCodes1, ",", "','");
            pracCodes = "'" + NameCodes1 + "'";
            using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyConnectionString"].ConnectionString))
            {
                string sql = "SELECT name AS FieldName3, t2.[PHO_Name] AS FieldName2, t1.field1 AS FieldName1 FROM table3 t3 " +
                                "LEFT JOIN table2 t2 ON t3.PHO = t2.PHO_ID " +
                                "LEFT JOIN table1 t1 ON t2.DHB_ID = t1.DHB_ID " +
                                "WHERE IDPractice IN (" + NameCodes1 + ")";
                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn))
                {
                    using (SqlDataAdapter ad = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
                    {
                        ad.Fill(table2);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    GridView8.DataSource = table2;
    GridView8.DataBind();
}
```

Comment: Why don't you show the relevant part: the GridView and the table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<strike>If i understood you correctly, you're creating a table dynamically. This have to be done on every postback in Page_load at the latest.</strike>

So you simply need to bind the GridView `if(!IsPostBack)` but the table on every postback, hence separate both mentods from each other.

After you've edited your question i know what you mean. So you need to create the DataSource of the `GridView` according to user input.

You need to `DataBind` your GridView from `Page_Load` only `if(!IsPostBack)`(with default data). Then you could handle the `SearchBox` `TextChanged` event(or a button that applies the search). From there you need to `DataBind` the GridView accordingly with the search-parameters.

Comment: So I need to provide the GridView with some dummy default data first? Then call GetData() in a different method?

Comment: @vegetas_angel: You don't need to load it at all if you don't want. But then the grid including the footer is not shown. I'm not sure if this is ok.

Comment: The Grid with the footer is the only one being done this way, so it needs to be shown. 
I have tried with the dummy data and using textchanged. It has loaded the table properly but when I try to click the 'InsertOP' button (which should make the footer visible and databind the grid with GridView8.DataBind()) the table seems to disappear. Any idea why?

Comment: Nevermind - I just had to call GetData() instead of DataBind! Thanks heaps! :)